# Get the row count of WMI Query in C++

Tags: c++, c, windows, wmi, wmi-query

the following vbscript gives the number of rows returned by the WMI query.

```
strComputer = "." 
Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:\\" & strComputer & "\root\CIMV2") 
Set colItems = objWMIService.ExecQuery("SELECT * FROM Win32_PnPSignedDriver",,0)
Wscript.Echo colItems.count
```

Same thing I need to achieve in C++.

In C++, passing the query using IWbemServices->ExecQuery method

```
....
//initializing and connecting WMI
....
hr = services->ExecQuery(bstr_t("WQL"), bstr_t(strClass), WBEM_FLAG_FORWARD_ONLY |   WBEM_FLAG_RETURN_IMMEDIATELY, NULL, &results);
```

I tried the above but dont know how to get the row count of the query. Can someone please suggest how to get it done in C++

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK that property is not present in the WMI COM API, to obtain the number of records you must use the [`IEnumWbemClassObject`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa390857%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) interface and count the instances returned your self.

Answer (score 0):

You need to iterate the results:

```
IWbemClassObject* pclsObj = NULL;
int uRows = 0;

while (pEnumerator)
{
  HRESULT hr = pEnumerator->Next(WBEM_INFINITE, 1, &pclsObj, &uReturn);

  if (0 == uReturn)
  {
     break;
  }

  uRows++;
}
```

**uRows** is your "row count".